How To Correctly Render Packed Texture ARM/ORM Map?
I have a model that came with 4 textures including a packed map (so roughly I think 7 in total). After some digging/research I found this Pack Map is sometimes referred to as ORM or ARM. From what I understand the file Map.png is a packed map where each RGB channel is associated to some property (according to this post where RED is alpha, GREEN is ambient occlusion and BLUE is subsurface scatter. Feel free to correct me.). How would I correctly render these textures? I tried extracting each of the values from each RGB channel and connecting them into a Principle BSD (and in another attempt AO BSD) but failed miserably. The render options dont align with all the RGB channels for the packed map, base, ramp and normal maps.
I added screenshot with the Packed map to get a better idea with what im dealing with along with a list of each file
4 Texture Files:

BaseColor.png - this map is mostly transparent except for blue details on the characters face (see preview below)
on the model like characters face
Maps.png - this appears to be a packed map (but I am unsure what channel
is mapped to which or if it is correctly made)
Normal.png - nothing
special to note
Ramp.png - this looks like some color filter that is applieed (Im not entirely sure nor have I seen something like this before)


Below is my render configuration of what I have tried. With the idea of packed map in mind I tried splitting them into Red, Green and Blue channels. Green is for AO but theres no option for that. Red is alpha so I connected it to alpha. Blue is subsurface but theres no option for that. Im not entirely sure if this is the correct shader since many options are missing. Princple BSD has no AO to connect to. But AO BSD has AO while missing other components.

Can someone help clear up the following:

What shader do I use in this setup?
Is the RGB colors I explained correct channel mapping?
How should the render pipeline look like so that the model renders like in the image below?

Below is the preview the artist provided of what the model should look like:

UPDATE:
I reached out to the artist and they provided different texture files and how to setup. They used a Princple BSDF that had a simple Diffuse texture and Emissive for the face. Im a bit confused whether the texture was incorrect to begin with or if they re-processed the texture into one file?
Here is the new workflow with the 2 textures:

